# Does the folder created by `npm run build` contain the react runtime engine?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, build

I've read that React can be thought of as a [UI Runtime](https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/), which made me think it was an application that ran on a server.

Further research showed this was false, and React apps can be served statically. If true, doesn't that mean `npm run build` must add a copy of the react runtime engine to the static files?

Comment: that "runtime engine" is just Javascript, so when you build the application you get one or more static JS files, which include the entire (JS) React source code. So in that sense the answer is "yes".